# Beego installation failure in Mac

Tags: go, beego

I am trying to install Beego. I have Go installed in using dmg file. When I run the `go env` it gives the following output:

```
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/Users/achu/Development/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/Users/achu/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/achu/Development/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/5_/tcc_r8_d1d58nsf4pstyq0q00000gn/T/go-build781638269=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

I executed `go get github.com/astaxie/beego` and when I tried to run `bee version` command it gave the error

> Unknown command 'bee'

Please tell me if I have missed any steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the proper path to your `PATH` environment variable. This is typically done by editing `~/.bashrc`, or your environment's equivalent, with a line such as:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

Answer (score -2):

> Please check  your `$GOPATH/bin` folder

In your case it's:

```
/Users/achu/Development/go
```

There you will find the binary file of your installed packages. (`bee`)

Then run/execute it!

Comment: It is there. But how can I make it available globally

Comment: Move or copy  the binary file to your `/bin` folder

Comment: I don't know, why someone downvoted this. anything wrong?